# Building an Access connection string using .NET to find the current directory>

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

I have a line of code that builds the connection string to an Access database.

```
private static string ConnectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
            @"Data source= C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\AccessFile.mdb";
```

How can I use any of these bits of code: `Path.GetDirectoryName()` or `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear where in the string you'd like to insert this, but I'll assume you want to replace the entire directory path.  To do this, you *could* just concatenate the strings together using `+`:

```
private static string ConnectionString = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + 
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory) +
    @"\AccessFile.mdb";
```

Alternatively (and probably better) would be to use `string.Format`:

```
private static string ConnectionString = string.Format(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source={0}\AccessFile.mdb", 
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory));
```

Comment: i vey surprised for the quick answer i going to try it soon

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DAL 
{
    public class OLEDBhelper
    {
        private static string ConnectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
            @"Data source= " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory) + "\AccessFile.mdb";
    }
}
```